# how to show url provider name from regular expression

Tags: angularjs, regex

i have the requirement like this ,

http://indianexpress.com/article/india/ram-nath-kovind-for-president-which-parties-support-his-candidature-and-how-the-scales-weigh-4712714/

now am showing whole link,now the requirement is ,to show only indianexpress(when i click on this link it should navigate)

the code is:

```
     var detectUrls = function(value) {
          var retval = value;
          if(retval != null) {
            var urlRegex = /(((\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/)|(www\.))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:(),.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
            retval = value.replace(urlRegex, function (url,b,c) {
              var url2 = (c == 'www.') ?  'http://' +url : url;
              return '<a href="' + url2 + '" target="_blank">' + url2 + '</a>';
            });
          }
          return retval;
        };
$scope.post.postText = detectUrls($scope.post.postText);
```

I am display whole link using url2(above)

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/wo646xyg/

Comment: displaying https:// (from the fiddle code)

Comment: In my console, I see [`<a href="http://indianexpress.com/article/india/ram-nath-kovind-for-president-which-parties-support-his-candidature-and-how-the-scales-weigh-4712714/" target="_blank">indianexpress.com</a>`](https://jsfiddle.net/wo646xyg/). Did you use **my regex** or yours? Use mine, and  `(c == 'www.')` should be replaced with `(b == 'www.')`. Just try *my* code.

Comment: i will update you what i am getting with your fiddle

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew screen shot added please check that once

Comment: That means your input is different, or there is some copy/paste error.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes every time the input will change.From that input will display the Name

Comment: I can repro that issue if I use `/((\b(...`. If I use my `/((?:\b(...` (note the `?:`), all works as expected. Please post the code you have *now*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay i will update you if i face any issue

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew it is working fine and when i type www.google com it just displaying google.co.(it should display www.google.com)

Comment: Wait, that seems a bug that it matches spaces.  I think the regex should not match `www.google com`, but `www.google` only. See https://jsfiddle.net/wo646xyg/1/. I doubt I understand the requirements now.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew is it possible to display only name (without .in or .com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest regrouping the parts of the regex to only have 2 relevant capturing groups, one for the protocol, and the other for the domain name with any subdomains. 
The pattern is

- `((?:\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/)|www\.)` -  Group 1 (`b`):

  - `(?:\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/)` - word boundar followed with `http` or `https`, `ftp`, or `file`, folllowed with `://`
  - `|` - or
  - `www\.` - `www.` substring
- `([^\s\/]+)` - Group 2 (`c`): 1+ chars other than whitespaces and `/`
- `(?:\/?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:(),.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])?` - an optional sequence of:
- `\/?`  - 1 or 0 `/`s
- `[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:(),.;]*` -  0 or more chars defined in the character class
- `[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]`  - 1 single char from the defined class.

Then, the code would look like

```js
var detectUrls = function(value) {
      var retval = value;
      if(retval != null) {
        var urlRegex = /((?:\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/)|www\.)([^\s\/]+)(?:\/?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:(),.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])?/ig;
        retval = value.replace(urlRegex, function (url,b,c) {
          var url2 = (b == 'www.') ?  'http://' +url : url;
          return '<a href="' + url2 + '" target="_blank">' + c + '</a>';
        });
      }
      return retval;
    };
    
var res  = detectUrls('http://indianexpress.com/article/india/ram-nath-kovind-for-president-which-parties-support-his-candidature-and-how-the-scales-weigh-4712714/  www.google.com');
console.log(res);
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

To only display names you need to tweak the regex a bit, `([^\s\/]+)` will change to `(?:[^\s\/]*\.)?([^\s\/.]+)\.[^\s\/.]+`:

- `(?:[^\s\/]*\.)?` - an optional sequence of 0+ chars other than whitespace,
  `/` followed with `.`
- `([^\s\/.]+)` - Group 2 (`c`) that will match 1+ chars other than whitespace, `/` and `.`
- `\.`  - a `.`
- `[^\s\/.]+` -  1+ chars other than whitespace, `/` and `.`.

```js
var detectUrls = function(value) {
      var retval = value;
      if(retval != null) {
        var urlRegex = /((?:\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/)|www\.)(?:[^\s\/]*\.)?([^\s\/.]+)\.[^\s\/.]+(?:\/?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:(),.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])?/ig;
        retval = value.replace(urlRegex, function (url,b,c) {
          var url2 = (b == 'www.') ?  'http://' +url : url;
          return '<a href="' + url2 + '" target="_blank">' + c + '</a>';
        });
      }
      return retval;
    };
    
var res  = detectUrls('http://indianexpress.com/article/india/ram-nath-kovind-for-president-which-parties-support-his-candidature-and-how-the-scales-weigh-4712714/  www.google.com');
console.log(res);
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```